# How to convert string into timestamp in Presto (Athena)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I want to convert datatype of string (eg : '2018-03-27T00:20:00.855556Z' ) into timestamp (eg : '2018-03-27 00:20:00').

Actually I execute the query in Athena :

```
select * from tb_name where elb_status_code like '5%%' AND 
date between DATE_ADD('hour',-2,NOW()) AND NOW();
```

But I got error :

> SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:100: Cannot check if varchar is BETWEEN timestamp with time zone and timestamp with time zone
>
> This query ran against the "vf_aws_metrices" database, unless qualified by the query. Please post the error message on our forum or contact customer support with Query Id: 6b4ae2e1-f890-4b73-85ea-12a650d69278.

Reason :
Because date in string format and have to convert into timestamp. But I don't know how to convert it.

Answer (score 37):

Try to use `from_iso8601_timestamp`. Please visit below address to learn more about timestamp related functions: https://docs.starburstdata.com/latest/functions/datetime.html

```
presto:tiny> select from_iso8601_timestamp('2018-03-27T00:20:00.855556Z');
            _col0
-----------------------------
 2018-03-27 00:20:00.855 UTC
(1 row)
```

I believe you query shoul look like:

```
select * from tb_name where elb_status_code like '5%%' AND 
from_iso8601_timestamp(date) between DATE_ADD('hour',-2,NOW()) AND NOW();
```

Comment: What to do when the dataetime is string type and contains  29/09/2020 20:21 format?

Answer (score 12):

I used the following way and it worked for me.

```
date_parse(eta,'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s')
```

Please go through the documentation below for detailed outputs

[datetime in presto](http://teradata.github.io/presto/docs/127t/functions/datetime.html)

Comment: Which is great except that, for some reason, Athena does not support Presto's "%i"  reporting "Illegal pattern component: i". Same for %I. Less significantly the question uses a "T" instead of a space as the date/time separator.

Comment: i used mention function but not working for leap year date_parse('02/29/1977','%m/%d/%Y') showing error

Comment: @RajeshQa please refer to prestoDB documentation for corner cases. If you get the solution, please comment here. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I did:

select parse_datetime('2020-12-20 16:05:33','yyyy-MM-dd H:m:s') as dta;

parse_datetime(string, format) → timestamp with time zone

seealso:

https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#java-date-functions

https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html

Answer (score -2):

You can try something like below.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2018-03-27T00:20:00.855556Z','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/KGM48831)

Comment: This works only when the input is a TIMESTAMP, not a VARCHAR